# Using Loop to extract climatic information from Library in R

Tags: r, loops, extract, sequence, code-climate

I have a quite large database. I need to extract climate information from the "Nasapower" Library.

My reduced dataset looks like this:

```
api_decimal<- data.frame (
    AP_COD = c("LOM_A", "LOM_L", "LOM_M", "LOM_LA", "LOM_CO"),
    LAT_DEC = c(25.628,
                25.641,
                25.415,
                25.435,
                25.424),
    LONG_DEC = c(7.300,
                 7.314,
                 7.450,
                 7.449,
                 7.443)
    
  )

api_decimal$site <- paste(api_decimal$LAT_DEC, ",", api_decimal$LONG_DEC)
```

I tried to make a loop to extract the "daily" "Temperature (TM2)" information for the years 2014 to 2020 for all sites (latitude, longitude), but the loop doesn't work:

```
years <- c("2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019")
for (i in seq_along(years)){
  year <- years[[i]]
  
  for(j in seq_along(nrow(api_decimal$site))) {
    sites <- as.numeric(api_decimal$site[j, ])
    ag_d <- get_power(
      community = "ag",
      lonlat = sites,
      pars = "T2M",
      dates = years,
      temporal_api = "daily"
    )
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thank in advance

Comment: Can you specify exactly what you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get errors? Are you not getting the output you expect -- if so, what exactly is the output you expect? You seem to be overwriting the same variables in so your loop so I'm not sure where you expect all the values to go.

Comment: @MrFlick ag_d data frame was not created. The output should contain the daily temperature information for each geographical coordinate and year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few problems with he code.  First, since `nrow(api_decimal$site)` is `NULL`, `seq_along(nrow(api_decimal$site))` evaluates to `logical(0)`.  Instead, you want `seq_along(api_decimal$site)`.    There were a couple of problems with your call to `get_power()`.  First, the  `lonlat` argument is meant to be a vector of length two.  The way you're doing it in the code creates a single string with two decimals separated by a comma.  When you turn this into a numeric value, it doesn't make two numeric values, it only makes a single `NA` value.  Instead, you can just use the longitude and latitude coordinates that are already in the data.  Finally, the `dates` argument wants length 2 character vector giving the start and end dates in YYYY-MM-DD format.  You could make this by pasting your year variable to "-01-01" for the start and to "-12-31" for the end.

If the loop had run, you would have also been overwriting `ag_d` with every iteration.  You could solve that by initializing `ag_d` outside the loop and then using `rbind(ag_d, new_result)` to accumulate the results as you move through the iterations of the loop.  This code should work:

```r
library(nasapower)
api_decimal<- data.frame (
  AP_COD = c("LOM_A", "LOM_L", "LOM_M", "LOM_LA", "LOM_CO"),
  LAT_DEC = c(25.628,
              25.641,
              25.415,
              25.435,
              25.424),
  LONG_DEC = c(7.300,
               7.314,
               7.450,
               7.449,
               7.443)
  
)

years <- c("2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019")
ag_d <- NULL
for (i in seq_along(years)){
  year <- years[[i]]
  for(j in seq_along(api_decimal$LONG_DEC)) {
    ag_d <- rbind(ag_d, 
                  get_power(
                    community = "ag",
                    lonlat = c(api_decimal$LONG_DEC[j], api_decimal$LAT_DEC[j]),
                    pars = "T2M",
                    dates = c(paste0(years[i], "-01-01"), 
                              paste0(years[i], "-12-31")),
                    temporal_api = "daily"
    ))
  }
}
```